# HTML5 video - detected when current time equals a certain value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video, html5-video, single-page-application

I am trying to detect when the current time of a html video equals a particular value, but I think I am going about it the wrong way.

JS to load video source (works fine)

```
document.querySelector("#videoBox > source").src =  $scope.videoUrl;
var video = document.getElementById("videoBox");
```

JS to detect current time

```
if (video.currentTime == 0.2){
    alert("Time reached!");
   }
```

If I check the currentTime==0 it is correctly detected before the video starts, however it doesn't work for other durations.
Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the document is loaded the if statement is checked once and not again. So if you check for `video.currentTime == 0` is true but for `video.currentTime == 0.2` is false, try something like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(checkTime, 100);
function checkTime(){
if(Math.floor(video.currentTime) == 2){
  alert("Time reached!");
  clearInterval(interval);
}
}
```

In this way you will check for the time every 100 miliseconds and if time is 0.2 the interval is stoped

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked when I changed the first line to setInterval(checkTime, 100); If you edit your answer I'll accept it

Comment: Also the interval was missing the time value to stop on but using math.floor seemed to fix it.  if(Math.floor(video.currentTime) == 2)

Comment: Edited :) Don't know why setInterval('checkTime()',100) didn't work for you as i always use it that way.